# How do I stop OpenVPN from using every interface on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I've previously dealt with PPTP, which would give me the PPP0 interface that I could bind services to. However, OpenVPN covers all interfaces.

How can I make it only work on a single interface, thus allowing the rest of the network to work without going via OpenVPN? I'm using a tun device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your friend - https://kindlund.wordpress.com/2007/11/19/configuring-multiple-default-routes-in-linux/ - basically (from the mouthes of the OpenVPN guys), the solution has not within OpenVPN, its with routing.  You have not specified your OS or exactly what you are trying to do though, so its difficult to provide specifics here.  [ You can influence routing from the OpenVPN config, but until we know what you are trying to achieve - including configs and route tables we can't provide specifics ]

Comment: This was enough info, I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and figured it out from there :) Thanks!

Comment: Could you maybe provide the details? I'm in a similar boat and would like to know what you did.