# How do I make OpenVPN not my default connection in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn, openvpn

Similar to [How do I stop OpenVPN from using every interface?](https://superuser.com/questions/559106/how-do-i-stop-openvpn-from-using-every-interface) but this question is for Windows 10, not Ubuntu.

I am successfully using OpenVPN to connect to my AWS Client VPN endpoint. However while OpenVPN works to connect to AWS, it takes over my default route and thus I can't access the internet when connected.

I can see there's an interface made by OpenVPN:

[image]

```
$ Get-NetIPAddress | select IPAddress, InterfaceAlias


IPAddress                    InterfaceAlias
---------                    --------------
172.17.112.1                 vEthernet (WSL)
169.254.172.104              Ethernet 3
169.254.108.136              Local Area Connection* 2
169.254.157.10               Bluetooth Network Connection
169.254.141.13               Local Area Connection* 1
192.168.1.147                WiFi
10.1.0.130                   Local Area Connection <- This is my OpenVPN IP address & adapter
127.0.0.1                    Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
```

I have read the [OpenVPN wiki which states](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/319-how-do-i-make-the-windows-network-adapter-my-default-adapter-again) which is very out of date:

> When a new network adapter is added, Windows tends to put it at the top of its internal adapter list, making it the default for certain functions.
> In many cases this is undesired -- unfortunately I'm not aware of any way that the TAP-Win32 driver installer can programmatically override this default.
> Luckily, this can be fixed manually by going to Control Panel / Network Connections / Advanced / Advanced Settings. In the top subwindow of the dialog box, move the TAP-Win32 adapter down from the top position.

Obviously these instructions are very out of date for Windows 10. I am trying to convert them to Control Panel, however the 'Advanced Settings' menu doesn't seem to match what I'd expect:

[image]

**How do I make OpenVPN not my default connection in Windows 10?**

**Update** I've also tried following [this advice on setting network interface priorities](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-priority-order-network-adapters-windows-10):

The UI won't let me change the `metric` without setting a static IP (which I don't want to do, I'm using DHCP).

[image]

Trying Powershell

```
Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex 14 -InterfaceMetric 60
```

Which shows lowered priority for `OpenVPN` compared to `WiFi`:

```
$ Get-NetIPInterface

ifIndex InterfaceAlias                  AddressFamily NlMtu(Bytes) InterfaceMetric Dhcp     ConnectionState PolicyStore
------- --------------                  ------------- ------------ --------------- ----     --------------- -----------
9       WiFi                            IPv4                  1500              50 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
14      OpenVPN                         IPv4                  1500              60 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
```

But the behavior still persists - connecting to OpenVPN breaks my internet connection.

Comment: Are you sure it breaks because it uses the VPN? Did you do a tracert? If it does setting the metric of the interface is not enough you will need to edit the metrics of the routing table.

Comment: depends on the server configuration you are connected to. the server config should not have a redirect default gateway option and should push only routes you want to use for tunneling.

Comment: @Zina could you tell me more about the redirect default gateway option?

Comment: [check out this topic on OpenVPN forum](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=17942), and should be in the OpenVPN Documentation/Examples (it is a long time since I configured those)